# Cells.Replace functions for similar wording

Tags: excel, vba

I inherited an Excel macro for use with my companies' bank deposits. I was able to read line by line and figure out how the macro worked.

There's so many `Cells.Replace` functions that 32 bit Excel throws

> "Compile Error: Procedure too large".

I need to slim it down. For example:

```
Cells.Replace What:="DIRECT DEPOSIT COMPANY A OF CALIFORNIA", Replacement:="COMPANY", LookAt:=xlPart, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
  ReplaceFormat:=False

Cells.Replace What:="DIRECT DEPOSIT COMPANY A UTAH SECTOR", Replacement:="COMPANY", LookAt:=xlPart, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
  ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Both are from the same company, and treated as such afterwards, but because they have slightly different names I've been adding a new function for every one.

I assumed that because it is using 'LookAt:=xlPart" I'd be able to say:

```
Cells.Replace What:="DIRECT DEPOSIT COMPANY", Replacement:="COMPANY", LookAt:=xlPart, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
  ReplaceFormat:=False
```

But I end up with "COMPANY", + everything after what is specified in the What function tacked onto the end.

Is there a more streamlined method of finding all cells starting with "DIRECT DEPOSIT COMPANY A", disregarding anything after that, and replacing with just "COMPANY"?

Comment: It would help to show some example of "before" and "after" so it's clear what you want as the intended outcome.  If you're getting "Procedure too large" that's a sign your Sub needs a total re-write: consider moving the "find" and "replace with" texts to a worksheet, then having the code read that sheet line-by-line and run the replace for each pair of values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can run repeated "replace all if starts with" replacements:

```
Sub tester()

    ReplaceStartsWith "COMPANY A", "COMPANY"
    ReplaceStartsWith "COMPANY B", "COMPANY"

End Sub



Sub ReplaceStartsWith(startsWith, replaceWith)
    Cells.Replace what:=startsWith & "*", replacement:=replaceWith, lookat:=xlWhole
End Sub
```

[image]

Note you might want to add a space at the end of the `startsWith` if you don't want (eg) "COMPANY A" to match "COMPANY ADVANCED"